# Is 'fascinates" and "is fascinating" interchangeable?

Tags: present-continuous, progressive-aspect

What's the difference between:

1. This fascinates me
2. This is fascinating to me

I just wanted to know because I am curious.

Comment: Yes, they basically mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do both make grammatical sense. I would think the second one sounds more natural, but to be honest, either one is fine. Be sure to consider the context as either one could sound awkward depending on surrounding words.

Comment: So are they the same

Comment: pretty much, yes

Comment: Thank you the most